# Сложение и вычитание дат. Java

Tags: java, дата

**Пример**:
11.09.2016 - 13.08.2013 = 29.0.3
11.09.2016 + 13.08.2013 = 24.5.4030

На входе должна быть строка типа

> 11.09.2016 - 13.08.2013

На выходе

> 29.0.3

У меня идея была в том, чтобы входные даты перевести в миллисекунды и произвести операции. НО при конвертации результата (с миллисекунд в дату) получается ересь.

Каким образом можно складывать/вычитать даты?

Comment: Какая же ересь получается? Можно посмотреть?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, начало исчисления в unix времени 1 января 1970 года, а значит любая дата будет начинать отсчитываться от этой даты

Comment: @Ziens и к чему эта инфа?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в этом и будет ересь, если просто переводить

Comment: Дело в том, что разность двух дат - не дата, а интервал времени. Сумма двух дат - вообще непонятно что.

Comment: @Ziens а если я выведу дату меньше 1970 года ваша вера пошатнется похоже и будет депрессия пару лет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вам же уже сказали, если интервал времени перевести в дату, то получим ДАТУ, а не интервал времени. Какая вера? Если хотите предложить что-то дельное, так предлагайте, а если нет, то не несите ерунды.

Comment: Одинаковый ли должен получиться результат `2015.03.01 00:00 - 2015.01.31 00:00` и `2015.03.31 00:00 - 2015.03.02 00:00`? (И то и другое - ровно 29 суток). Сложение двух дат - вообще операция лишенная смысла.

Comment: @Ziens как сообщения об интервалах соотносится с ложным высказыванием что `любая дата будет начинать отсчитываться от этой даты` ?

Comment: По-моему это не совсем сложение/вычитание дат и проще написать свои функции расчета..... типа сложение: сложить годы... потом сложить месяцы.. если число больше 12 то остаток остается месяцем а в годах прибавляем 1... примерное шаманство и с днями производить....... с вычитанием в том же направлении делать только обратно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Смотрим комментарий к конструктору класса Data, который принимает время в миллисекундах: Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я нигде не указывал, что невозможно вывести дату меньше 1970, просто время в миллисекундах будет отрицательным

Comment: @Ziens `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z");
        
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)));` выведет `2 дек 292269055 до н.э., 19:47:04` ....напомню `Long.MIN_VALUE` равно значению `-9223372036854775808` .... что я делаю не так?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да все у вас так, прочитайте мой комментарий выше. И вообще я не пойму чего вы добиваетесь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java 8 уже есть готовые классы для работы с классами.

**Сложение дат**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class AdditionDate {

    public String getOperator() {
        return "+";
    }

    public void getResult(LocalDate firstDate, LocalDate secondDate) {
        LocalDate result = firstDate.plusYears(secondDate.getYear()).
                plusMonths(secondDate.getMonthValue()).plusDays(secondDate.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Вычитание дат**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class SubtractionDate {

    public String getOperator() {
        return "-";
    }

    public void getResult(LocalDate firstDate, LocalDate secondDate) {
        Period period = Period.between(secondDate, firstDate);
        System.out.println(period.getYears() + "." + period.getMonths() + "." + period.getDays());
    }
}
```

Вычитание лучше делать через Period, так как если использовать операторы minusYear()/minusMonth()/minusDat(), то некорректно считается разница.

Правда вывод периода будет типа y.m.d -> 1.2.3

Answer (score 3):

**Разность двух дат нельзя представить (корректно) в виде YY.MM.DD.** Можно считать как предложил Алексей Шиманский (разность лет; разность месяцев, если отрицательна, уменьшаем на 1 разность лет; потом дни), но результат будет лишен смысла.

Проблема в следующем:

1) Возьмем 4 даты: а) 31-01-2015, б) 01-03-16, в) 31-01-2016, г) 01-03-2016.
Если вычитать даты (б-а и г-в) так, как вы предлагаете, у Вас получится одинаковый результат (0 лет 1 месяц 1 день). Но на самом деле между датами в первом случае 29 дней, во втором - 30.

2) Пример из моего комментария:
`2015.03.01 - 2015.01.31` и `2015.03.31 - 2015.03.02`. Разница и там и там одинакова - 29 суток. А у Вас получатся разные результаты.

Вообще, вычитая одну дату из другой, мы теряем "привязку" к конкретному месяцу и году. Результат вычитания двух дат - просто интервал времени, не привязанный к конкретному году. Его можно выразить в секундах, минутах, сутках, но нельзя - в месяцах или годах.

Сумма двух дат вовсе лишена какого-либо смысла, хотя ее как раз можно вполне корректно вычислить сложив `time since epoche` и перевести обратно в дату.

Comment: В общем я с вами согласен, но например я считал на http://datacalc.ru/ и как-то они это сделали, причем вполне корректно

Comment: @Ziens результат вычитания 2 дат в виде YY.MM.DD может иметь смысл *только* в случае привязки к одной из двух первоначальных дат. Сам по себе он бессмысленен.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения через экземпляр Calendar

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar t2 = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 9, 26);
    Calendar t1 = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 8, 13);
    System.out.println(getDifference(t2, t1));
}

private static String getDifference(Calendar t1, Calendar t2) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("> ");
    result.append(t1.get(Calendar.YEAR) > t2.get(Calendar.YEAR) ? t1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - t2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            : t2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - t1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    result.append(":");
    result.append(t1.get(Calendar.MONTH) > t2.get(Calendar.MONTH) ? t1.get(Calendar.MONTH) - t2.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            : t2.get(Calendar.MONTH) - t1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    result.append(":");
    result.append(t1.get(Calendar.DATE) > t2.get(Calendar.DATE) ? t1.get(Calendar.DATE) - t2.get(Calendar.DATE)
            : t2.get(Calendar.DATE) - t1.get(Calendar.DATE));
    return result.append(" < ").toString();
}
```

выглядит насыщенно но отрабатывает благополучно)

Comment: Если вставить дату из примера, то получается > 3:1:2 < , а не 3:0:29

Comment: Проверьте, что получится для дат 2016/9/26 и 2013/10/13.

Comment: @andy.37, > 3:1:13 <, онлайн калькулятор показывает, что должно быть 2 года 11 месяцев 13 дней

Comment: @Ziens@ andy.37 - да фактически ну учитывается аккамуляция текущего месяца/года - дополню