# Проблема с условиями для вывода разници между датами

Tags: javascript, дата

Пользователь вводит две даты в формате "December 13, 2014 00:00:00" а в ответ получает "прошло 2 года, 1 месяц 7 дней ...", вот никак не могу понять как сделать вывод в формате который указан выше.Простите за код, я новичок.

```js
function timeFromFirst(form) {
  var first = new Date(form.firstDate.value);
  var second = new Date(form.secondDate.value);
  var year = second.getFullYear() - first.getFullYear();
  var month = second.getMonth() - first.getMonth();
  var day = (second.getDate() + 1) - (first.getDate() + 1);
  var hours = (second.getHours() + 1) - (first.getHours() + 1);
  var minutes = (second.getMinutes() + 1) - (first.getMinutes() + 1);

}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <h3>Input date like "October 13, 2014 11:13:00"</h3>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="firstDate">
    <input type="datetime-local" name="secondDate">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="timeFromFirst(form)">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Вопрос задавался неоднократно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569937/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82-java?rq=1

Comment: @andy.37 , но там ответ дан для java с готовыми классами, а https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569963/221753 неправильно работает

Comment: @br3t Я, собственно, к тому, что разность дат и дата - принципиально разные сущности, и разность *не выражается* в годах.

Comment: @andy.37, почему `разность не выражается в годах`? Как и в чем тогда измерять временной промежуток между двумя событиями? Опять-таки, автор исправил заголовок на "вывод даты", но по телу вопроса и сниппету видно, что речь идет о разности дат.

Comment: @br3t сколько лет между вчера и сегодня? 1/365 года или 1/366? А сколько месяцев? (1/28-1/31) И почему `вчера - сегодня != -(сегодня - вчера)`?

Comment: @andy.37 , да, необходимо использовать не только годы, но и месяцы, и дни. Ведь используем же мы спокойно `в этот день год назад...`, а не `а вот 365 дней назад...`

Comment: @br3t `в этот день год назад` - нечетко сформулированная дата (как и многое, что произносят люди). Чтобы объяснить ее компьютеру, нужно дополнительная формализация (Вы, конечно, вправе ввести ее по собственному усмотрению). А вот `365 дней назад` - как раз будет понятно компьютеру.

Comment: @andy.37 , осмелюсь предположить, что, ввиду замечательности нашего календаря, автор вопроса согласен пожертвовать точностью в пользу удобства.

Answer (score -3):

Предлагаю для саморазвития сделать ручками:

1 не високосный год - 365 дней.

1 високосный год - 366 дней.

Как отличить високосный от не високосного?

> Високосные года делятся нацело на 4. Однако из этого правила есть
>   исключение: столетия, которые не делятся нацело на 400, високосными не
>   являются.

Посмотрев на календарь можно узнать, сколько в каком месяце дней.

Код приводить не стану, ибо уверен, что при желании его можно найти и так.