# Разница дат.Перевод миллисекунд в года, месяца, дни, часы, минуты и секунды

Tags: javascript, дата, время

В переменной differ разница между двумя датами, не могу придумать как перевести её в формат вида: "Между датами прошло 2 года, 1 месяц, 6 дней..."

```js
function timeFromFirst(form) {
  var first = new Date(form.firstDate.value);
  var second = new Date(form.secondDate.value);
  var f = first.getTime();
  var s = second.getTime();
  var differ = s - f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <form>
      <p>
        <h3>Input date like "October 13, 2014 11:13:00"</h3>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="firstDate">
        <input type="datetime-local" name="secondDate">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="timeFromFirst(form)">
      </p>
    </form>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с условиями для вывода разници между датами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654969/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Это не дубликат вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в вашем случае допускается использование сторонних библиотек то я могу посоветовать [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) а в частности [Precise Range плагин](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/preciserange/) из этой библиотеки:

```
moment("2014-01-01 12:00:00").preciseDiff("2015-03-04 16:05:06");
// 1 year 2 months 3 days 4 hours 5 minutes 6 seconds
```

Если дополнительные библиотеки нежелательны или недопустимы то можно пойти по следующему [пути](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/6934016) доработав его под свои нужды:

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function timeFromFirst() {
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
    , first = new Date(form.firstDate.value).getTime()
    , second = new Date(form.secondDate.value).getTime()
    , diff = new Date(Math.abs(second - first))
    , years = diff.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - 1970
    , months = diff.getMonth()
    , days = diff.getDate() - 1;
  var result = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Между датами прошло ' + years + ' лет, ' + months + ' месяца, ' + days + ' дня.';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h3>Input date like "October 13, 2014 11:13:00"</h3>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="firstDate" value="2000-01-01T00:33">
  <input type="datetime-local" name="secondDate" value="2017-04-21T00:33">
  <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="timeFromFirst(form)">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```